# Searching for a folder within a folder (Excel- VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am given a bridge plan number which is a 4 digit number. I need to find a folder corresponding that bridge. The folder name will carry the bridge plan number and some other random text (eg "1234- washington street"). I've written some code that is able to achieve this but it is very slow. I was wondering if someone can com up with a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks.

```
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject

Public Function FoundPlan(bridge_plan As String)

    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim planFolder As Folder
    Dim Path As String
    Dim i As String


    Path = "G:\some\path"
    'This is the directory path that carries my list of folders

    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)

    If Not Len(bridge_plan) = 4 Then
        FoundPlan = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    'If the given plan number is anything except 4 digits, the function returns 
    'nothing and exits

    For Each planFolder In objFolder.SubFolders

        If Not InStr(planFolder, bridge_plan) = 0 Then
            FoundPlan = Path & planFolder
            Exit For
        End If

    Next planFolder

    'For each subfolder in my directory I use instr to search for my number 
    'inside the folder path.

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. It doesn't need to loop through each folder

```
Public Function FoundPlan(bridge_plan As String) As String
    Dim planFolder As String, Path As String

    Path = "G:\some\path\"
    'This is the directory path that carries my list of folders

    If Not Len(bridge_plan) = 4 Then Exit Function

    planFolder = Dir(Path & bridge_plan & "*", vbDirectory)

    If Not planFolder = vbNullString Then FoundPlan = Path & planFolder
End Function
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what the "Dir" operator is doing. Right now this function is returning nothing even though a folder exists.

Comment: What's your path? Have you included the final `\ ` as well? `Dir` is a function which lists files and folders. By using the `*` it provides a fuzzy match for the name. [Reference](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php)

Comment: I didn't include a backslash in the `Dir` line so your Path would need to be equal to `Path = "G:\TSB\Bridge Shared\Bridge Plans\Bridge Plans-SCANNED\"`

Comment: Is the Dir operator able to search for the folder even though you can only supply it the plan number?

Comment: Yes by using the `*` asterisk you're finding the first folder with a partial match. No problem